# Match specific dots in sentences

Tags: java, regex

I want to add spaces where needed (after `.`) in sentences. When a `.` is not followed by another `.` or a space, a space should be added.

I've came up with that regex :

```
\.(?![ \.])
```

There is only one problem, if the `.` is at the end of the string, it should not be selected.

**Example :**

Here is a test sentence...Here is another sentence.

Should select : Here is a test sentence..`.`Here is another sentence.

but my solution select :

Here is a test sentence..`.`Here is another sentence`.`

After the regex, all groups will be replaced by ". ". This part is already done and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShellFish put me on the right track, came up with this working regex :

```
\.(?![\.\s])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use positive lookahead

```
\.(?=\w)
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your pattern to

```
\.(?![. ]|$)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hF5bY4/3)

```
\.              # "."
(?!             # Negative Look-Ahead
  [. ]          # Character Class [. ]
  |             # OR
  $             # End of string/line
)               # End of # Negative Look-Ahead
```